# Maintain login token across multiple HttpURLConnection requests

Tags: java, session, authentication, token, httpurlconnection

Sorry to ask you this but I am kinda new in Java.

I have the following classes:

```
protected class LoginMethod{
        public LoginMethod() throws MalformedURLException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException{
        URL url = new URL("http://example.com/login");
        Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        params.put("username", user);
        params.put("password", password );

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        try{
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

            Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            for ( int c = in.read(); c != -1; c = in.read() )
                token += String.valueOf((char)c);
            System.out.println(token);
            new LoggedIn();
        }catch(IOException es){
            System.out.println(es);
        }
        } 

    }
```

And this returns a JSON String with some token.
And the next class :

```
protected class DoStuff{
        public DoStuff() throws MalformedURLException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException, ParseException{
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            URL url = new URL("http://example.com/DoStuff");
            Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();

            params.put("Do", "Stuff");
            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
                if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                postData.append('=');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
            }
            byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                try{
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

                Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                for ( int c = in.read(); c != -1; c = in.read() )
                    stuff +=(char)c;
                System.out.println(stuff);
                new LogOut();
                }catch(IOException er){
                    System.out.println(er);
                }

        }

    }
```

This should return the DoStuff thing. But because I don't know how to keep session between those classes I get 401 error.
My question is how to keep the session between those classes or a tip how to put them into a single class that supports session keeping in mind they are called by separate buttons.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper answer is the following: 
In the second class we need to json decode the token received and add

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
```

This works. Thanks StackOverflow for everything.

Answer (score 0):

If the mentioned "http://example.com" is a webservice, the token which you received in the response is having session information. All you need to be do is to send the token back by setting in request header while calling dostuff method.

login response :

```
 { "token":"ewryoiuasdjhie8417098412","expires":"jun 10 2015"}
```

while calling dostuff

```
conn.setRequestProperty("token", "ewryoiuasdjhie8417098412");
```